# Add View to ScrollView and then scroll to bottom: Which callback is needed?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-scrollview

In a Dialog I have a `ScrollView` which contains a (vertical) `LinearLayout`; the bottommost View in the `LinearLayout` is a `TextView` that starts out with `android:visibility="gone"`.

At some point during the program I want to `setVisiblity(View.VISIBLE)` on the `TextView` and display an error message. And because the `ScrollView` could be in any position at this point, I want to scroll to the bottom, when the error message appears.

I tried all of:

```
scrollView.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN);

scrollView.scrollTo(0, tvLoginError.getTop());

scrollView.scrollTo(0, tvLoginError.getBottom());
```

and each of those in each of these:

```
scrollView.post(...)

tvLoginError.post(...)

scrollView.getViewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(...)

tvLoginError.getViewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(...)

scrollView.getViewTreeObserver.addOnPreDrawListener(...)

tvLoginError.getViewTreeObserver.addOnPreDrawListener(...)
```

None of these works properly. The scolling always stops when the newly visible `TextView` is just outside the `ScrollView` or when it is halfway visible - but never truly at the bottom. (The ones with `ViewTreeObserver` would work in principle but only if I don't remove the callback after the first update. But if I keep it around longer, I have no way of knowing when to remove it instead (...?)

Please tell me what callback I need to use to scroll to the bottom after the `TextView` is completely visible.

Answer (score 1):

Since I found this question when looking for the answer, I figure I'll save the next person some time.

The underlying problem is that you are calling your `scroll` command too early. If you add something to the view, the layout changes don't really happen until the view is redrawn. If you write `content_view.getHeight` to the log where you are doing the `scroll` call, you will find that the value is unchanged by adding to the content.

The solution is to do something like the following:

```
scroll_view.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Get content_view
        scroll_view.smoothScrollTo(content_view.getWidth(), content_view.getHeight());
    }
});
```

This resolves the problem because you are posting to the main event loop and it will run after the events already queued up -- which includes rendering the layout.

NOTE: I just found that in at least one case this didn't work as expected because it still ran the post runnable too early. That is quickly solved by using a short delayed post, but I'd love to understand why the above solution doesn't always work. Here is an example (Java 8 lambda version) using postDelayed:

```
view_port.postDelayed(()->{
        LinearLayout content = scroll_view.findViewById(R.id.content);
        scroll_view.smoothScrollTo(0, content.getHeight());
    }, 200);
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can try this way

use "postDelayed" method

delay few millisecond then do what you want to do